# Why do "or" act this way?

Tags: python, syntax, python-2.7

I was trying many different things on Python 2.7.3 and I came across this code:

Input:

```
x = 4
y = 7
x or y
```

Output:

```
4
```

According to the [document](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not), `or` is a Boolean Operations. **Isn't `or` suppose to yield `True` or `False` only ?**

So, I tried some more with this code:

Input:

```
a = 3
b = 2
a or b
```

Output:

```
3
```

Then at this point, I assume that the code will return the first argument of the expression.

**Why do Python gave me this output ? What really happen behind Python `or` operation?**

Comment: The documentation that you linked to explains exactly how it works.

Comment: `or` will return the first expression if it is truthy, and the second if the first is falsy.

Comment: If you want boolean value returned you can do `bool(x or y)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

georgesi's answer perfectly answers the exact question you asked—but then so do the docs you linked to, because he's just quoting from those docs. So, presumably you want more.

You could be asking two things:

1. *Why* was Python designed this way, when my native intuition/favorite language says `or` should return a `bool`?
2. *How* does Python implement this?

Since you bolded the question "**What really happen behind Python `or` operation**", I'm guessing it's the latter.

Remember that there are multiple implementations of Python, and they're free to implement things however they want, as long as they meet the spec set by the reference docs. But usually, when people ask "how does Python do this?" they mean "how does the CPython implementation do this?"

First, let's look at some bytecode:

```
>>> def f():
...     return 1 or 2
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1) 
            3 JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP      9 
            6 LOAD_CONST               2 (2) 
      >>    9 RETURN_VALUE
```

What does this mean? In Python-esque pseudocode, it's like this:

```
top = 1
if top:
     goto 9
else:
     del top
top = 2
label 9
return top
```

If you want to understand better (and CPython is the implementation you care about), you just need to know that the CPython bytecode interpreter is a simple stack machine, and the code for that stack machine is inside the file `ceval.c`. So, we can find the `JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP` code [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Python/ceval.c#l2443). (The `LOAD_CONST` opcodes just push the constant value onto the stack, so that `w = TOP()` can find them. I don't think we really need to look into that to understand how `or` works.)

You can see that it's a bit more complicated.

Mainly this is because it optimizes the `if top` part by checking `if top == False` and `if top == True` before calling the C-API equivalent of `bool(top)`, and because it has to handle exceptions from that `bool` call. But it's also optimizing stack usage. Without explaining how `DISPATCH` and `FAST_DISPATCH` work it's hard to get too precise, but the basic idea is, it avoids popping values off the stack just to push them back for return.

But that's "What really happen behind Python `or` operation?"

---

You also bolded "**Isn't `or` suppose to yield `True` or `False` only ?**" So, that brings us back to question 1.

First, remember that duck typing is pretty central to Python. `or` is supposed to yield something which can be used as if it were `True` or `False` anywhere that it matters. You're specifically supposed to write things like `if foo:` rather than `if foo == True:` (or `if foo is True:` or `if foo != False:` or whatever), so you shouldn't be caring about the difference.

Second, about half the languages agree with your that a "boolean operation" should strictly return boolean-typed values, while half of them disagree. Even in languages that aren't built around duck typing, like C. So, how's a language designer to decide?

The "C++ style" of making the `or` operator always return `bool` avoids copies, allows better static type enforcement by the compiler, and gives better dynamic type information to the programmer. The first two are completely irrelevant in Python, and the last is generally only useful when you're writing code that relies on types instead of duck typing, which is generally considered unpythonic.

The "C style" of making it return the first truthy value (or the last falsy value) as-is makes for a slightly simpler implementation, and offers the programmer a sort of shorthand for the ternary `if`-`else` expression.

Back when Python didn't have a ternary `if`-`else`, this was an easier call to make. Nowadays, maybe it's a closer call—especially since some people hate `a or b` as shorthand for `a if a else b` and consider it unpythonic.

But history is on the side of what's already there; nothing gets changed unless there's a compelling reason, and a close call that arguably might go in the opposite direction depending on your taste is not a compelling reason.

Comment: Thank you. This is just what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation :

> x or y :          if x is false, then y, else x   (1)

for every integer different from zero, `x or y` will return `x`

Answer (score 2):

from the [doc link](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#or) you provided:

> The expression x or y first evaluates x; if x is true, its value is
>   returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is
>   returned.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the only situation in which `or` should return an object that is false is if both operands are false.

With this behavior in mind, we can see that in the situation where the first operand is true, we already know that both operands are not false. This means that the entire expression should evaluate to true, regardless of what the second operand is. The first operand (which is true) is returned.

In the case that the first operand (which we'll call x) is *false*, `x or y` is logically equivalent to `y`. If y is true, both x and y are not false, so `x or y` is true. If y is false, both x and y are false, so `x or y` is false. This is why y is returned if x is false.

This approach, which is known as short circuit evaluation, is less computationally expensive when x is false, since y need not be evaluated unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

The `or` operator in Python will return the first value if it is considered true, or the second if the first is false and the second is true.  In the case both are false then it will return `False`.  In this case both 4 and 3 are true values hence they are returned.  If you instead used 0 you would see the second value used

```
x = 0
y = 3
x or y
```

This will return 3

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered, but you still might ask yourself why this behavior would make sense.

Here's a simple usecase:

```
port = int(raw_input("Port number (default 5000): ") or 5000)
```

In this context, the behavior of `or` (and `and`) makes perfectly sense. Another one:

```
url_scheme = enable_https and 'https' or 'http'  # although this can be also expressed as:
url_scheme = 'https' if enable_https else 'http'
# but i personally prefer the above, because i can read it
# more easily due to the two possible values being closer together
```

Answer (score -1):

It's kind of like a shorthand if statement. I use it all the time in JS coding.

You can use `AND` in the same way.

```
var x = 0;

x && console.log('x is not truth-y');
x || console.log('x is false-y');
```

As a bunch of other people have already said, the `&&` or `||` operators **evaluate** the expression to the left of them and then, depending on if we're talking about `&&` or `||` and depending on if the evaluation was truth-y or false-y, they will either stop, or continue to **evaluate** the expression on the right side of them.

Comment: This kind of thing is usually not considered Pythonic. For one thing, in Python, unlike JS, many things are not expressions (such as Python 2.x's equivalent to `console.log`, the `print` statement), so you _can't_ do this. But even when you can, this isn't any shorter than `if x: print('x is truthy')`, and it's less obvious (and TOOWTDI is central to the Python zen).

Comment: More importantly… this isn't actually relevant to the OP's question, even in JS. It doesn't matter whether JS returns `true` or the result of `console.log` in your second statement; you're only evaluating it for the side-effect. But what the OP was asking about is why Python doesn't return `true` instead of the value of the expression.